# Casting a System.__ComObject in C# via reflection

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to cast a `System.__ComObject` to an interface type using reflection. I have tried using `Convert.ChangeType(Object,Type)` but c# then throws this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Object
>   must implement IConvertible.

So is there any possible way to cast a general `__ComObject`  using reflection to its correct type so i can then call its methods via reflection? And yes, it has to be done via a method which doesn't involve telling the compiler ahead of time what the object type is!

Comment: "I'm attempting to cast a System.__ComObject to an interface type" - Could you explain Why?

Comment: If you can't cast it up front in your code then the odds that you can do it later, using Reflection, are vanishingly small.  A COM object implements well defined interface types, they are defined in a type library which you have to import with Tlbimp.exe

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm trying to cast it because the method i call returns an object. I'm calling the method from an untyped dlr language so i would like to cast it once by giving it the correct type and then invoke methods on it later on using reflection. I cant use object.getType if the object is still a __ComObject. Of course i could specify the type every time or store the type, but that wasn't really the point of the questionX)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, no.

The _ComObject needs to implement an interface which the .Net runtime knows about. This will either be an interface which you get from `QueryInterface` or `IDispatch`.

If it's the former, you have to know what the interface is, and then you have to describe the interface to .Net using the [ComImportAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comimportattribute.aspx) on the interface.

If the COM object implements `IDispatch`, you can dynamically invoke members on it. In .Net 4.0 and above, this can be done easily by using the `dynamic` keyword. If you are using an earlier version of .Net, you can call [`InvokeMember()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3dhzwy.aspx) on the type returned by `GetType()` or else cast to [`IReflect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.ireflect.aspx) and use that interface to call methods.

The best case is if you get a Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW) for the COM object, either by running `tlbimp.exe` yourself on the COM library or getting a Primary Interop Assembly (PIA) for it, usually from the COM library author.

Answer (score -4):

For any object to be type casted you need to be sure it belongs to that particular type.
You can verify thisfirst by checking using "is" operator.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28VS.71%29.aspx