# Can't cast a collection property from a VB library in a C# application

Tags: .net, casting, class-library, c#-to-vb.net

I'm trying to use a old VB library in a C# application.

This library has a couple of classes, one in particular has a method returns an instance of itself example: `Posts post = new Posts().GetLast();`

The Posts class has a property Comments that is actually of type object. In VB I can iterate trough the Comments property like trough a `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection`, but in C# I cannot cast the property, in order to use it, to anything. I tried importing the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace, and typecasting to Collection, but it didn't work returning a error that said System.__ComObject has to be cast to a spcific Interface from the library.

Inside the collection there are objects that implement the interface IComments, I cannot cast to the interface because it is a collection of the interface.

I also tried casting to ICollection (the interface that is implemented by  `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection`) but with no positive result.

Any idea on how to solve this issue, my only way out of this problem is by changing the C# application to a VB one (not that difficult, but still a thing that i would prefer avoiding)

Comment: did you go through answer to this question? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151861/casting-a-system-comobject-in-c-sharp-via-reflection

Comment: I did see this specific answer, and if i understand correctly, this means that a typecast is not possible if I do not have control of the class library (I cannot implement any interface on the object)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trying all the Interfaces I can think of , using the `as` operator and comparing the result null I found out that the the property can be cast as IEnumerable (logicaly `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` implements `ICollection` and `ICollection` implements `IEnumerable`).