# Passing a C# class instance back to managed code from JavaScript via COM

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, com, webbrowser-control

The basic outline of my problem is shown in the code below.  I'm hosting a WebBrowser control in a form and providing an `ObjectForScripting` with two methods: `GiveMeAGizmo` and `GiveMeAGizmoUser`.  Both methods return the respective class instances:

```c#
[ComVisible]
public class Gizmo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

[ComVisible]
public class GizmoUser
{
    public void doSomethingWith(object oGizmo)
    {
        Gizmo g = (Gizmo) oGizmo;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(g.name);
    }
}
```

In JavaScript, I create an instance of both classes, but I need to pass the first instance to a method on the second instance.  The JS code looks a little like this:

```js
var 
    // Returns a Gizmo instance
    gizmo = window.external.GiveMeAGizmo(),

    // Returns a GizmoUser instance
    gUser = window.external.GiveMeAGizmoUser();

gizmo.name = 'hello';

// Passes Gizmo instance back to C# code
gUser.doSomethingWith(gizmo);
```

This is where I've hit a wall.  My C# method `GizmoUser.doSomethingWith()` cannot cast the object back to a Gizmo type.  It throws the following error:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Gizmo'

Unsure how to proceed, I tried a couple of other things:

- Safe casting `Gizmo g = oGizmo as Gizmo;` (`g` is `null`)
- Having the classes implement `IDispatch` and calling `InvokeMember`, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2152193/94197).  The member "name" is `null`.

I need this to work with .NET framework version lower than 4.0, so I cannot use `dynamic`.  Does anybody know how I can get this working?

Comment: What does `oGizmo` look like in debugger? or is it always null?

Comment: @Abhinav: its type is `System.__ComObject`.  If I try `oGizmo.GetType().GetMembers()`, it returns `null` (same for `GetProperties()` and `GetMethods()`.

Comment: Can you show 'GiveMeAGizmo()' code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How interesting. When we receive the `oGizmo` object back in `doSomethingWith`, it is of the type `Windows Runtime Object`. This behavior is consistent between JavaScript and VBScript.

Now, if we explicitly specify **`MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)`** on the return value of the `GiveMeAGizmo()` method, **everything works fine**, the object can be cast back to `Gizmo` inside `doSomethingWith`:

```
[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
public class ObjectForScripting
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
    public object GiveMeAGizmo()
    {
        return new Gizmo();
    }

    public object GiveMeAGizmoUser()
    {
        return new GizmoUser();
    }
}
```

Still, if we specify `UnmanagedType.IDispatch` or `UnmanagedType.Struct` (the default one which marshals the object as COM `VARIANT`), the problem is back.

Thus, there's a workaround, but no reasonable explanation for such COM interop behavior, so far.

**[UPDATE]** A few more experiments, below. Note how obtaining `gizmo1` is successful, while `gizmo2` is not:

**C#**:

```
// pass a Gizmo object to JavaScript
this.webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("SetGizmo", new Object[] { new Gizmo()});

// get it back, this works
var gizmo1 = (Gizmo)this.webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("GetGizmo");

// get a new Gizmo, via window.external.GiveMeAGizmo()
// this fails
var gizmo2 = (Gizmo)this.webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("GetGizmo2");
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var _gizmo;

function SetGizmo(gizmo) { _gizmo = gizmo; }

function GetGizmo() { return _gizmo; }

function GetGizmo2() { return window.external.GiveMeAGizmo(); }
```

It's only a guess, but I think such behavior might have something to do with .NET security permission sets, imposed by [`WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm very impressed that you went the extra mile to help out here.  Your answer works perfectly as far as I can tell, so the green tick is yours.

Comment: @AndyE, no problem. `WebBrowser` and everything around is the area of my special interest :)

Comment: ah, I'll remember that for the next problem then ;-).  The project I'm working on employs a lot of advanced techniques for hacking the WebBrowser control, but we've been stuck a couple of times on some complicated stuff (and I'm no expert in .NET, if I'm honest!).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things

1. Find out the type of object as described [here](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/mz2006013.aspx).
2. Extract the actual object outta it using [Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getobjectforiunknown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (read till the end, there is an interface to implement).

Comment: Have you actually tried that? It doesn't work in the OP's case, because his original object of type `Gizmo` is already a *managed* object. Somehow, it gets wrapped as "Windows Runtime Object" when passed back from JavaScript. For the same reason, `Gizmo g = (Gizmo)Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(oGizmo, typeof(Gizmo))` doesn't work either.